# unzip with dirty characters in file name

Tags: r, character-encoding, unzip

I am trying to unzip a file in R and then import it as CSV.
The file name has a “dirty“ character, i.e. should be a German umlaut, but it is in fact "則".
I am using a Mac OS.

```
library(curl)
URL <- "https://www.intervista.ch/media/2020/03/Download_Mobilitäts-Monitoring_Covid-19.zip"   
h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h, ssl_verifyhost = 0, ssl_verifypeer=0)
curl_download(url=URL, "download_mobilitäts-monitoring_covid-19.zip", handle = h)
unzip("download_mobilitäts-monitoring_covid-19.zip", files = "Mobilit則szweck_pro_Tag.csv")
```

gives me

"Warning: In unzip : requested file in Zipfile not found"

It works if I want to extract another file from the same folder without problematic characters:

```
URL <- "https://www.intervista.ch/media/2020/03/Download_Mobilitäts-Monitoring_Covid-19.zip"   
h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h, ssl_verifyhost = 0, ssl_verifypeer=0)
curl_download(url=URL, "download_mobilitäts-monitoring_covid-19.zip", handle = h)
unzip("download_mobilitäts-monitoring_covid-19.zip", files = "Mittelwerte_und_Median_pro_Tag.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

just a matter of finding out the file name as read by R

```
library(curl)
URL <- "https://www.intervista.ch/media/2020/03/Download_Mobilitäts-Monitoring_Covid-19.zip"   
h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h, ssl_verifyhost = 0, ssl_verifypeer=0)
dir.create("testdir")
curl_download(url=URL, "testdir/download_mobilitäts-monitoring_covid-19.zip", handle = h)
setwd("testdir")
unzip("download_mobilitäts-monitoring_covid-19.zip")
myname <- myname[grepl("weck_pro_tag",myname, ignore.case = T)] # here is the file name
res <- read.csv(myname)
head(res)
        Date    Total WorkSchool  Leisure  Shopping     Other
1 2020-01-01 34.05609   2.576243 25.89024  5.177567 0.4120363
2 2020-01-02 43.89093   2.997753 31.30430  9.355982 0.2328906
```

Comment: I am getting the following error after "unzip": cannot open ./Description_des_variables_du_suivi_de_la_mobilit�_Covid-19.pdf' : Illegal byte sequence

Comment: how are you trying to open it? it is a pdf so read.csv won't work.

Comment: I am not trying to open it ... I am getting the error after the 'unzip' command. R cannot read the file name.

Comment: If I try 'read_csv' with the file name you found out, I am getting the error: 'No such file or directory'

Comment: I am not getting to this point because there is still the error after unzip: Illegal byte sequence

Comment: You should **REALLY** be using Rstudio and execute line by line interactively rather than running the full script at once. That way, you'd be able to run the following lines even if there was an error in one... Have to say this is quite basic. Anyway, now the code is modified. what do you have in the `myname` variable?

Comment: I cannot create `myname` because unzip does not work (tried running it line by line). I have to tell R to ignore the pdf when unzipping the folder.

Comment: maybe you have a different filename, maybe there is a problem when you copy the character  `"` from stackoverflow. if you dont post the error youre having i cant help.